# Graphs and charts

Tags: php

I am making and coding a web application and I am looking for a FREE opensource or a tutorial on how to display information in a chart basis.

My information is how many players are on a popular game server, I can get all this information but I need a way to display it. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

http://minecraft-server-list.com/server/16760/

You see near the top of the page there is a rssponsive chart? I am looking for a tutorial or a download or any help on how to make one .. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is my favorite. It's relatively easy and of excellent quality.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your comment! I found this very useful, but is there an easy way to customize it? I need to be able to implement data and I have no knowledge on java or jquery.. just html and css and a friend has done all the PHP..

Comment: Packt Publishing has published a book about Highcharts. You can find it in [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-Highcharts-Joe-Kuan/dp/1849519080/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1370726580&sr=8-1). You will also find plenty of tutorials for Highcharts. If you really want to use it, you **will** have to spend some time on Javascript and jQuery (a Javascript framework, actually). Javascript is a relatively easy language to learn and use, so your time to learn it will not be a waste, that's for sure. I hope my answer helped you.